# Get everything in a string after the 4th '/'

Tags: php, split

Can somebody please help me out.  I would like to return everything in a string after the fourth '/'.

The file name that I am trying to edit is:

/students/levans10/public_html/cs130a/group4

so i want to include cs130a/group4.

I would also like to isolate the levans10 so the string between the 2nd and 3rd '/'.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Yes i have. I currently have this `function makeURL() {
 $filelist = glob(getcwd()."/*");
 $path= getcwd();
 $filename = substr(strrchr($path, "/"), 1);
 
 
  if ($filelist != false) {
    print "<p>Here are some files:</p>";
    foreach ($filelist as $file) {
      $url = "http://hills.ccsf.edu/~levans10/".$filename."/" . substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);
      print "<p>$url</p>";
    }
  } else {
    print "No files in current directory!";
  }
}

makeURL();
` But $filename is only getting me the last part of the string and i need more than that.

Comment: explode on your separator (`/`) and then you can access any of the parts individually.

Comment: @John Doe This isn't a code writing service. Jonathan has given you a real good hint.

Comment: @BigScar I am aware this is not a code writing service.

Comment: @JohnDoe ^ Don't post code in comments! Edit your question with your code/attpempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string by slashes, then you can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to extract the part which you want and with [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) you can print it again)

```
<?php

    $str = "/students/levans10/public_html/cs130a/group4";
    $arr = explode("/", $str);
    echo implode("/", array_slice($arr, 4));//echo implode("/", array_slice($arr, 2, 1));

?>
```

output:

```
cs130a/group4  //levans10
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been working with explode but the array_slice part was what I was missing.  Now my function will be portable to my group members :).

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = '/students/levans10/public_html/cs130a/group4';
$parts = explode('/', $input, 5); // split string into max 5 parts
```

Afterwards, `$parts[4]` will be `cs130a/group4` and `$parts[2]` is a student name.

FYI:

```
var_dump($parts);
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(8) "students"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "levans10"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "public_html"
  [4]=>
  string(13) "cs130a/group4"
}
```